# Create multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I need help creating an array within an array using this data.  This data is already in an array like this:

```
[0] => META>>DisplayName=Donald Trump
[1] => META>>EmailAddress=TheDon@rnc.com
[2] => META>>EmployeeID=E13342
[3] => CLOUD>>DisplayName=Hillary Clinton
[4] => CLOUD>>EmailAddress=Hill@dnc.com
[5] => CLOUD>>EmployeeID=E13423
[6] => AD>>DisplayName=Bernie Sanders
[7] => AD>>EmailAddress=Bernie@dnc.com
[8] => AD>>EmployeeID=E121233
```

I'm trying to turn it into something like this:

```
array(
       [meta] => Array
          (
              [DisplayName]=>Donald Trump
              [EmailAddress]=>TheDonald@rnc.com
              [EmployeeID]=>E666420
              [EmployeeType]=>E
          )
)
```

What I have so far but it's not working:

```
$properties = array("DisplayName",
                    "EmailAddress",
                    "EmployeeID",
                    "EmployeeType")

 $data = array();
 foreach($output as $line) {
     $sep = explode(">>",$line);                 
     $data[$sep[0]] = array();
     for ($x=0;$x<count($properties);$x++) {
         $split = explode("=",$sep[1]);
         $data[$sep[0]][$p] = $split[1];
     }

 }
```

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: Is this supposed to contain multiple people?

Comment: where should `$p` come from? change that to `$properties[$x]` and it should work

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos he's tried what he's showed!? Ain't that enough?

Comment: @DobotJr i reverted your edit - showing what you have tried is important

Comment: (you're missing a semicolon after $properties definition)

Comment: What I tried is failing big time..@jeff, yeah that didn't work.

Comment: @georaldc yes, multiple people

Comment: Are those properties always going to be what you need to define a single person? Will it always appear in that order?

Comment: what did not work? changing `$p` to `$properties[$x]`? Can you be clearer about _WHAT_ doesn't work? whats the output? errors?

Comment: @georaldc yes and yes

Comment: If you'd had posted that real data in first place we wouldn't have spent 30minutes for _nothing_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieve like this:

```
$output = [
 'META>>DisplayName=Donald Trump',
 'META>>EmailAddress=TheDonald@rnc.com',
 'META>>EmployeeID=E666420',
 'META>>EmployeeType=E',
];

$result = array();

foreach ($output as $value) {
  $meta = explode('>>', $value);
  $property = explode('=', $meta[1]);
  $result[$meta[0]][$property[0]] = $property[1]; 
}

var_dump($result);
```

http://ideone.com/Twq9gr

Comment: OP said (in a comment) that 'meta' isn't always meta. So you might want to change that detail!

Comment: changed $result['meta'][$property[0]] = $property[1]; to $result[$meta[0]][$property[0]] = $property[1];

Works perfectly..thanks man!

Comment: This is the cleanest and easiest to understand solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is exactly as shown in your question, you can just iterate the array, use `substr` to eliminate the duplicate `META>>` part of the line,  and `explode` on `=`:

```
$data = [];
foreach($output as $line){
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', substr($line, 6));
    $data['meta'][$key]=$value;
}
```

Comment: getting error; sorry not familiar with  with "list".  

 syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('

Comment: `"If the data is exactly as shown in your question"` Yeah i kind of expected there where undeclared complications. Please edit your question to provide all the detail needed, including enough sample data to show the variations (eg multiple people, unwanted data)

Comment: Re the error, i missed `$` from the beginning of the `$value` variable - corrected

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
foreach ($output as $line) {
    list($keys, $value) = explode('=', $line);
    list($key, $attr) = explode('>>', $keys);
    $data[$key][$attr] = $value;
}
```

Comment: that might be working, but feels like a hacky thing (the if $key = 'EmployeeType thing)

Comment: The problem is the OP's data sample just goes line by line, so I had to define a stopping point where I would move to a new person

Comment: Hmm, more details keep getting added. Now I see that meta can change

Comment: just add it after that one foreach?! `$output` is one person only. To be fair, it's not statet in the question how the data really looks like, so that hack might be needed. - NO, after updated question.... can't add it after foreach. sry

Comment: I've updated my answer to take into account changing keys

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a best solution, but it will work:

```
<?php

$output[] = 'META>>DisplayName=Donald Trump';
$output[] = 'META>>EmailAddress=TheDonald@rnc.com';
$output[] = 'META>>EmployeeID=E666420';
$output[] = 'META>>EmployeeType=E';
$output[] = 'CLOUD>>DisplayName=Hillary Clinton';
$output[] = 'CLOUD>>EmailAddress=Hill@dnc.com';
$output[] = 'CLOUD>>EmployeeID=E13423';
$output[] = 'AD>>DisplayName=Bernie Sanders';
$output[] = 'AD>>EmailAddress=Bernie@dnc.com';
$output[] = 'AD>>EmployeeID=E121233';

$properties = array("DisplayName",
                    "EmailAddress",
                    "EmployeeID",
                    "EmployeeType");

$data = array();
foreach($output as $line) {
    $sep = explode(">>",$line);
    if(!isset($data[$sep[0]])){
        $data[$sep[0]] = array();
    }   
    $split = explode("=",$sep[1]);
    foreach ($properties as $p) {
        if($split[0] == $p) {
            $data[$sep[0]][$p] = $split[1];
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["META"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["DisplayName"]=>
    string(12) "Donald Trump"
    ["EmailAddress"]=>
    string(17) "TheDonald@rnc.com"
    ["EmployeeID"]=>
    string(7) "E666420"
    ["EmployeeType"]=>
    string(1) "E"
  }
  ["CLOUD"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DisplayName"]=>
    string(15) "Hillary Clinton"
    ["EmailAddress"]=>
    string(12) "Hill@dnc.com"
    ["EmployeeID"]=>
    string(6) "E13423"
  }
  ["AD"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DisplayName"]=>
    string(14) "Bernie Sanders"
    ["EmailAddress"]=>
    string(14) "Bernie@dnc.com"
    ["EmployeeID"]=>
    string(7) "E121233"
  }
}
```